# Changing the font size with \emph

Tags: fontsize, emphasis

In the `.tex` document I created, the emphasis command `\emph{text}` is frequently used (note that I use `\documentclass{llncs}` ). However, the `.pdf` preview shows the emphasized text as smaller that the plain text. What would be the way to change the font size for the text in `\emph{text}`. I would be good if one is able to set the option at the beginning, and not change every occurrence of `\emph{}`.

Comment: Please, show a minimal example.

Comment: i have noticed italic text looking smaller, on occasion.  the effect is never visible when i print out.  have you checked how your stuff looks when printed?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm surprised that there is that much to take into account with such a simple task. With `huge` in the answer below, the emph. text looks a lot bigger with Adobe. Your suggestion is that it would look normal when printed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
\let\oldemph\emph
\renewcommand\emph[1]{{\huge\oldemph{#1}}}
```

For future reference (for other users), the [llncs `documentclass` is available here](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip)

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\let\oldemph\emph
\renewcommand\emph[1]{{\huge\oldemph{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Here is some \emph{emphasized} text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but the text is too large now. Which parameter. How could I specify the font size between `normal` and `large`?

Comment: @boy that's up to you! my pdf viewer shows the emphasized text as I would expect it. perhaps this is a viewer issue...

Comment: @boy That's why I asked for a minimal example. The "problem" can be just related to the viewer.

Comment: @boy, @cmhughes: This solution will break the use of `\emph` in the context of other fontsizes, `\huge` will be used everywhere, even if the surrounding font size is `\tiny`. On my system I don't have any problem with llncs + `\emph`. So before a solution a minimal example and the pdflatex log file is needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer agreed